# glReleaseShaderCompiler() use cases

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I can not find any real life example of `glReleaseShaderCompiler` usage.

When would I use `glReleaseShaderCompiler` ? From the [khronos](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReleaseShaderCompiler.xml) description it states "This is a hint from the application that additional shader compilations are unlikely to occur".

It doesn't state if I must do it or what penalty do I have if I not use it. What are the gains except for the possible allocation of RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a reason this is a *hint*. The resources used by a shader compiler are completely implementation specific, but it will probably include reclaiming memory used for parsing, etc.

Regarding when to use it, if your program only loads shaders at initialization and never re-loads them, then that is a pretty good use-case. The same way it is suggested that you delete shader objects after linking your GLSL program to save memory since you are not going to continually re-link it.

Comment: Seems the only logical explanation. Thanks :)